# I want to change the title-line on an archive-page in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, translation, page-title

An archive-page gives as title: `Tag: <tag-title>` or `Category: <category-title>`. That's nice, but I like to have only: `<tag-title>` or `<category-title>`. 
As far as I can see, the standard title is constructed in `../wp-includes/general-templates.php` while `/wp-content/languages/nl_NL.mo` translates the "Tag:" and "Category:" part into Dutch.

So I tried to reach my goal by translating `Tag: %s` into `%s`; that worked, till Wordpress Translations were updated. Translating the child theme's `nl_NL.mo` didn't work. So I guess this is not something in the theme, but i Wordpress.

I tried to change the code in `/wp-includes/general-templates.php` and that worked - till WordPress was updated. So what can I do to make the changes of the title-line on my archive-pages sustainable?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You learned the most valuable lesson: never alter WP core files. You should use the `get_the_archive_title` filter to do this. Here's an answer on the WP stack overflow: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/179585/remove-category-tag-author-from-the-archive-title

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create and activate a child theme, find the php template file in the parent theme which is used for archive pages and which contains the title of the archive pages, copy that file to the child theme and change that copy it to your needs.

Typically, that page would use the `archive.php` file or the `category.php` file as a template, in less complex themes it could also just use the `index.php` file. Depending on the complexity of the parent theme, these files could also contain `include` functions which use additional template-part files - you'll have to find out yourself.